# Mount a shared windows folder in debian

Tags: debian, server-message-block, cifs

I am trying to mount a shared windows folder on my debian machine. I have installed smbclient and cifs-utils and then to mount it I enter `/etc/fstab` and apply the following line

```
//xx.xxx.xx.xx/Reports /var/www/csv/tmp cifs guest 0 0
```

Then I run a `mount -a` and recieve the following error

```
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

What could cause this error? The two machines are on the same network and can communicate without problems.

When I try to connect using smbclient I get this

```
root@foo:/var/log/samba# smbclient \\\\xx.xxx.xx.xx\\Reports
Enter root's password:
Connection to xx.xxx.xx.xx failed (Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)
```

Additional info:

```
root@foo:/home/foo# mount.cifs --verbose -o guest //xxxxxxxxxx/Repo              rts /var/www/csv/tmp
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=xxxxxxxxxx,unc=\\xxxxxxxxxx\Reports,guest,              user=,pass=********
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: Can you try to mount it with: `mount.cifs --verbose -o guest //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Reports /mnt/`  ans share the result

Comment: See my additional info. There is a VPN tunnel between these two machines. Are any ports required to be open?

Comment: Please check with `nmblookup -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` if the share is visible at all.